# Ruby - Is it possible to use FancyBox on button?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, fancybox

Is it possible to use FancyBox on button ?

```
 document.getElementById("btn-dispos").addEventListener("click", function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: path_to_load_plages_dispo_fournisseurs,
                    data: {ids : ids},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#btn-dispos').fancybox(
                            {type: 'ajax'},
                            fancyOptions
                        );
                    }
                });
            });
```

`<button id="btn-dispos">Results</button>`

It gives me the following error :

> The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it possible to use FancyBox on button ?" - Yes, it does not matter what html element you are using.

But your code does not make any sense. You are attaching custom click event handler for `#btn-dispos` element. And then, when user clicks your button, you are making ajax request and then you are attaching another click event handler to the previous element (by executing `$('#btn-dispos').fancybox()`). Why would you do that? If you want to display ajax response, then do that - `$.fancybox.open( your content )`

And lastly, your error message clearly states that content can not be loaded. Check your path.

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't know that .fancybox was attaching another click event handler.

Comment: So, basically, there are two ways of using fancybox - either you use `$('.selector').fancybox()` to start fancybox on click event or start fancybox immediately using `$.fancybox.open( your content )`